# Wordpress Remove a button from header if on that page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need help trying to figure out how to get a button removed if a user is on the profile page, or if they are on the page, the button could display as a current menu item only it is not clickable.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php  language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
      <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header class="site-header">
      <div class="container">
      <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a></h1>
       <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('/search')); ?>" class="js-search-trigger site-header__search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <i class="site-header__menu-trigger fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="site-header__menu group">
          <nav class="main-navigation">
            <ul>
              <li <?php if (get_post_type() == 'event' OR is_page('past-events')) echo 'class="current-menu-item"';
              ?>><a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('event');?>">Events</a></li>
              <li <?php if (get_post_type() == 'post') echo "class='current-menu-item'" 
              ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog'); ?>">Blogs</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
       <?php } ?>
          <div class="site-header__util">
            <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>

              <a href="<?php if (is_page() == 'profile') //Needs a function here ?>" class="btn 
              btn--small btn--dark-orange float-left push-right">View Profile</a>
              <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" class="btn
              btn--small btn--orange float-left push-right btn--with-photo">
              <span class="site-header__avatar"><?php 
              echo get_avatar(get_current_user_id(), 60); ?></span>
              <span class="btn__text">Log Out</span>
            </a>
            <?php } else{ ?>
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('/login') ?>" class="btn btn--small btn--orange float-left push-right">Login</a>
           <?php }?>
           <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            ?>
            <span href="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('/search')); ?>" class="search-trigger js-search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the button when on a specific page you can add the following code to your functions.php file.

```
function hide_button_on_page_4() {
    if ( is_page ( 4 ) ) {
        echo '<style>
            .btn.btn--small.btn--dark-orange.float-left.push-right {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_button_on_page_4' );
```

In the code above I hide the button when on the page that has 4 as its ID. You can modify `is_page(4)` with your corresponding page ID.

You can find the page ID in the URL of the page when you are in the editor. For example, if the URL of the page is `http://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit`, the page ID is `123`.